# Partial declarations must not specify different base classes windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-controls, mvvm-light

i'am getting this error her:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{

    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();


    }

}
```

my xaml is lile this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GameMemory.MainPage"..../>
```

besides it returns erro: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'GameMemory.MainPage.InitializeComponent()' and 'GameMemory.MainPage.InitializeComponent()'
any ideas please?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that one of the assemblies you referenced has a class named UserControl.
Check your using declarations.

Comment: will you explain more please, i didn't unterstood what are you trying to say.thanks